# Inherited res.users form error while opening with another user (not admin)

Tags: inheritance, odoo

I have a custom module with models that inherit from `res.users`. When I open the res.users.form with the Odoo admin account everything works fine, but when I open it with another user having the same access rights as admin I get the following error:

**Odoo Server Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eswaran/opt/opms-server/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/eswaran/opt/opms-server/openerp/http.py", line 574, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/eswaran/opt/opms-server/openerp/http.py", line 310, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eswaran/opt/opms-server/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eswaran/opt/opms-server/openerp/http.py", line 307, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/eswaran/opt/opms-server/openerp/http.py", line 803, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/eswaran/opt/opms-server/openerp/http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/eswaran/opt/opms-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 944, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/eswaran/opt/opms-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eswaran/opt/opms-server/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eswaran/opt/opms-server/openerp/models.py", line 1545, in fields_view_get
    xarch, xfields = View.postprocess_and_fields(cr, uid, self._name, etree.fromstring(result['arch']), view_id, context=ctx)
  File "/home/eswaran/opt/opms-server/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eswaran/opt/opms-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 841, in postprocess_and_fields
    self.raise_view_error(cr, user, message, view_id, context)
  File "/home/eswaran/opt/opms-server/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eswaran/opt/opms-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 369, in raise_view_error
    raise AttributeError(message)
AttributeError: Field `in_group_58` does not exist

Error context:
View `res.users.form`
[view_id: 153, xml_id: base.view_users_form, model: res.users, parent_id: n/a]
```

Comment: Can you edit the extension to `res.users` in your question?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm SOLVED above problem, after adding Access Rights to the user the problem get solved, thank you

Comment: Share the answer as answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you add Access Rights and ACL for that user [image: Adding an Application Access Rights]

ACL:

```
id : project_name_res_user_support_user 
name: project_name.res.user.support.user    
model: base.model_res_users     
group id : project_name.project_name_support_user   
permissions 1   1   1   1
```